# Using scons to generate latex source files and compile pdf

Tags: scons

I am working on a book. The chapters are stored in markdown
files. I use pandoc to generate the LaTeX-Files of the chapters.
Here is the structure of the project:

- Book/Manuscript: contains the markdown files
- Book/Editions/PDF/tex: contains the generated LaTeX files
- Book/Editions/PDF/Layout_1/: first layout of the book
- Book/Editions/PDF/Layout_2/: second layout of the book

I would like to use scons to generate the latex files and to
call LaTeX to compile the PDFs.

## *scons* set up

### Book/SConstruct:

The `SConstruct` script defines only where subsequent
scripts may find the chapters of the book:

```py
manuscript = Environment()
Manuscript.Replace(MARKDOWN_FILES = Glob('Manuscript/*.md'))

SConscript('Editions/PDF/SConscript', exports='manuscript')
```

### Book/Editions/PDF/SConscript:

This script defines the LaTeX environment:

```py
Import('manuscript')

PDF = Environment()

PDF.Replace(PDFLATEX='lualatex')

Export('PDF')

SConscript('tex/SConscript')

SConscript('Layout_1/SConscript')

SConscript('Layout_2/SConscript')
```

### Book/Editions/PDF/tex/SConscript

This script uses a generator function to create the LaTeX
files:

```py
import os

Import('Manuskript')

# write LaTeX file to Editions/PDF/tex
pandoc_action = 'pandoc -f markdown -o Editions/PDF/tex/{} {}'

def generate_pandoc_action(source, target, env, for_signature):
  # get the name of the target file
    tex_file = target[0].rstr().split(sep='/')[-1]
    return pandoc_action.format(tex_file, source[0])

env = Environment(ENV = os.environ)

markdownToLaTeX = Builder(generator = generate_pandoc_action,
                          suffix='.tex',
                          src_suffix='.md')

env['BUILDERS']['Pandoc'] = markdownToLaTeX

for input in Manuskript['MARKDOWN_FILES']:
    env.Pandoc(input)
```

I tried several other ways to call pandoc like a custom
builder. In any case, the LaTeX files were alway created in
directory `Book/Manuscript` and I had to move or copy them
to `Editions/PDF/tex`.

### Book/Editions/PDF/Layout_1/SConscript

This script calls lualatex to generate the PDF of the first
layout. The script for the second layout looks accordingly.

```py
Import('PDF')
basename = 'layout_'
pdf = PDF.PDF(basename + '.tex')
PDF.Clean(pdf, basename + '.synctex.gz')
Default(pdf)
```

### Problems

#### First problem

`Book/Editions/PDF/tex/SConscript` always processes all
markdown files in `Book/Manuscript` even if none of those
changed. I tried to use `VariantDir` to tell the script that
it should look for the targets in `Book/Editions/PDF/tex/`
but whenever I run `scons --debug=explain` it says:

```
scons: building `Manuscript/some_chapter.tex' because it doesn't exist
```

How do I tell *scons* to generate the targets in
`Book/Editions/PDF/tex/` and look for them in that directory
when it checks whether a target has to be created?

#### Second problem

`Book/Editions/PDF/SConscript` does not work as I
expected. My expectation was the *scons* would

1. enter directory `Book/Editions/PDF/tex` to generate the LaTeX
   files from all changed Markdown files
2. enter directory `Book/Editions/PDF/Layout_1` to generate
    the PDF for the first layout
3. enter directory `Book/Editions/PDF/Layout_2` to generate
    the PDF for the second layout

But *scons* only performs the second and the third step and
seems to either ignore the first step completely or to decide
that it does not have to perform it. Here is the output of
`scons --debug=explain`:

```
scons: Reading SConscript files ...
scons: done reading SConscript files.
scons: Building targets ...
scons: `Editions/PDF/Layout_1/book.pdf' is up to date.
scons: `Editions/PDF/Layout_2/book.pdf' is up to date.
scons: done building targets.
```

*scons* only calls the
Pandoc builder if I delete or uncomment the subsequent lines
in `Book/Editions/PDF/SConscript`. For example like this:

```
SConscript('tex/SConscript')

# SConscript('Layout_1/SConscript')

# SConscript('Layout_2/SConscript')
```

I do not understand why *scons* ignores `tex/SConscript`
when the other two scripts are active? What is the problem?

Thanks in advance

Maral

Answer (score 0):

You need to specify a target for builders (or have your emitter do it)..
Also all files when represented as strings

Try this and see if that helps.

## Book/Editions/PDF/tex/SConscript

```
import os

Import('Manuskript')

env = Environment(ENV = os.environ)

markdownToLaTeX = Builder('pandoc -f markdown -o $TARGET $SOURCE',
                          suffix='.tex',
                          src_suffix='.md')

env['BUILDERS']['Pandoc'] = markdownToLaTeX

for input in Manuskript['MARKDOWN_FILES']:
    # write LaTeX file to Editions/PDF/tex
    target = '#Editions/PDF/tex/'+File(input).file
    env.Pandoc(target, '#Book/'+input)
```

Comment: Thank you very much! Your advice solved both problems. I didn't know that a custom builder can be called with two arguments. The User Guide doesn't describe that option.

Comment: All builders can be called with mybuilder(target,source(s),CUSTOM_ENV_VARIABLES_FOR_THIS_BUILDER_INVOCATION).  Note it does show such an example in the Users Guide.. See here: https://scons.org/doc/production/HTML/scons-user.html#idm3678